# jQuery wait till AJAX page is fully loaded

Tags: jquery, ajax, image, load

I use AJAX to display content of page B on page A.

How can I make jQuery wait for everything to load (text, images etc.) before the content is displayed?

```
$.ajax({
    url:"pageB.html",
    beforeSend: function() {
        //show loading animation here
    }
    success: function(data) {
        //hide loading animation here
        $("body").append(data);
    }
});
```

I use beforeSend to show a loading animation to the user when the AJAX request is being processed. Now I want to "extend" the waiting time so that the loading animation does not disappear until all images are loaded.

I tried to initially hide appended data, wait for all images to load and then show content - 
 `$("body").on("load", "images class here", function() {//show content})` inside `success` but the event does not appear to fire.

Any ideas?

UPDATE:

Updated code:

```
$.ajax({
    url:"pageB.html",
    beforeSend: function() {
        //show loading animation here
    }
    success: function(data) {
        //hide loading animation here
        $("body").append(data);
        $("body").on("onload", "img", function() {//display content});
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to use direct event binding:

```
$("body img").on("load", function () { });
$("body .image-class").on("load", function () { });
```

Rather than delegated binding:

```
$("body").on("load", "img", function() { });
$("body").on("load", ".image-class", function () { });
```

Delegated bindings depend on the event bubbling, which not every event does. And it seems the `"load"` event -- at least, from an `<img>` -- is one that doesn't.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/DLy6j/

Comment: By far the best option! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In case of images you need to catch onload event for all the images.
So once you get success callback, find all the images, add "**onload**" event, and calculate once all the images have been loaded.

Comment: I updated my question with new code. Let's just assume for now that there is only 1 image to load. Is that code correct? It does not seem to work at all.

Comment: @Eleeist Event types with jQuery don't generally use the `on` prefix. So, it's just `"load"`: `$("body").on("load", "img", function() { });`