# .load() not firing for uncached images - jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-load

in safari and opera, the callback function of .load doesn't wait for uncached images to be fully loaded. with cached images it works perfectly fine.

the code is a little complicated, i'll try to simplify...

so, my js is this:

```
        $('#chatwindow_' + thread_id).load('/chat.php?thread_id=' + thread_id, function(){


            $('#chatwindow_' + thread_id).children('.chat_messagebox').load('/messages.php?sel=chat&latest_messages=10&thread_id=' + thread_id, function(){

//THIS IS BEING EXECUTED BEFORE THE IMAGES ARE FULLY LOADED, 
//BUT I EXPECT IT TO BE EXEC AFTER THE IMAGES ARE LOADED

                $(this).scrollTo('max',0);
                $('#chatwindow_' + thread_id).find('.messages_newcontent').focus();
        });


    });
```

messages.php?sel=chat:

```
<? include(gen_path("/messages_messagelist.php")); ?>
```

messages_messagelist.php:

```
while($x < $x_total){
load_attachments("message_".$message_row['id'], $max_width_of_att_field)
}
```

and finally the important snippet from the function:

```
return "<img src='/upload/attachments/".$attachments_row['id']."' width='160' class='download_file info_nextsibling' id='downloadfillabeobj_".$attachments_row['id']."'>"
```

and that's it - and if this final < img > is not cached, it gets fully loaded after the initial .load callback function is called - any ideas on how to wait for all the uncached images?

Comment: This questions already been asked and the answer given was what I suspected: You'll have to bind to the `img` load event, using `$.on()` in this case according to the accepted answer. Possible duplicate of [jQuery wait till AJAX page is fully loaded](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10822619/jquery-wait-till-ajax-page-is-fully-loaded)

Comment: oh, i didn't see that one - thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Look into David DeSandro's `imagesLoaded` [**jQuery plugin here**](https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded/).

From the docs:

> "you can't do .load() on cached images"