# window.onload equivalent after modifying the DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

When a page first loads we can use `window.onload` to make sure that all resources have loaded before we do something.

My question is, **if we modify the DOM (e.g. inserting some html based on an ajax request), is there any event that will fire when the document is in the 'loaded' state again?**  (e.g. when the html inserted contains multiple images).

(Solution with jQuery would be fine).

Comment: @Felix - I don't want to detect changes to the DOM, I want to detect when resources have been loaded after I change the DOM. All of those questions you reference are about detecting changes.

Comment: Maybe you should explicitly state this then. The DOM being ready and all resources being loaded are two different things.

Comment: Just to clarify, since you seem to make no distinction between load and ready, in jQuery the .load() happens when the page is completely rendered, while .ready() happens as soon as the DOM hierarchy is constructed. If your code relies on loaded assets (for example, you need to get dimensions of an image), you should use .load() to ensure that your code is executed when all needed assets are available. Otherwise you can use .ready() to speed up things, since your code will be executing while rendering.

Comment: Yes, good point @netrunner - I will amend the question...

Comment: @FelixKling - question edited.  Please could you remove the close for these unrelated questions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery Ajax wait until all images are loaded](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4774746/jquery-ajax-wait-until-all-images-are-loaded)

Comment: and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10822619/jquery-wait-till-ajax-page-is-fully-loaded.  I prefer `imageLoaded` for images and `load()` on particular `div` for other things.

Comment: @Jashwant - thanks! I agree those are pretty close to my question ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer:
NO.

The long answer:
if you know what you are looking for you can use mutation observers (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/MutationObserver). it is only support in new browser, and in some version of chrome it has memory leaks when used with closures.

BTW,
document.ready doesn't tell you if all (or any..) of the resources were loaded. it only tell you well, that the dom is ready (that is the load function, which will only fire after *all* resources (well, any resources that isn't requested using a javascript) were downloaded).

Comment: is there any update on this (`The short answer: NO`)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.done()`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/).

> **Description:** Add handlers to be called when the Deferred object is resolved.

Also there is jQuery plugin [**`See Here`**](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/)

Comment: Not sure I follow Dipesh.  I can attach a done to the promise from the ajax call, but this will only tell me when I have the data, not about any resources that have started to load after I insert this into the DOM. Or do you mean something else?

Answer (score 0):

I would say YES (I do not know if this is supported by all browsers. I use it in safari and chrome)

Testcase you can find here : http://maakmenietgek.nl/testcases/domready/ Please note that I cannot get it work in a fiddle, that's why a standalone testcase

The index.html looks like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <title>Testcase</title>
  <script src="jquery-1.8.2.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#clickme').click(function() {
        $.get('ajaxdata.html', function(data) {
            $('#addhere').html(data);
        });
      });
    })
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <p id="clickme">clickme</p>
  <div id="addhere">
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The data loaded with the `$.get` call looks like this

```
<p>added data</p>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        alert('added data');
    });
</script>
```

The alert shows after the html has been added to the DOM