# JavaScript AddedToStage equivalent

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, events, dom

What is the closest thing to ActionScripts ADDED_TO_STAGE event.
I need to know when a dynamically generated div has been added to another div

```
var myDiv = document.createElement("div");
$(someContainer).append(myDiv);
```

Comment: There is no native event. You need to add code yourself.

Comment: possible duplicate of [window.onload equivalent after modifying the DOM?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15700903/window-onload-equivalent-after-modifying-the-dom)

Comment: [**There you go.**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Events/Mutation_events)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using a function such as `appendChild` to add static text to the DOM, that's a synchronous event.  It will be added and rendered by the time your function returns.

If you're appending a child that depends on an external resource, you're looking for the `onload` event.  This works for the main document (`window.onload = function() { ... }`), and according to [What html tags support the onload/onerror javascript event attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/679704/can-you-put-the-javascript-onload-event-anywhere-besides-in-the-body-tag), body, frame, frameset, iframe, img, link and script.  (They apparently get their information from http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp, which is not nearly as good as straight from the spec, but I couldn't find the details in there.)