# My first attempt with AJAX - Stuck

Tags: ajax, jquery

This is in reference to http://jsfiddle.net/DLy6j/

```
     var echoHTML = '<img src="URL-TO-MY-IMAGE.JPG"/>';

        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: '/echo/html/',
            data: {
                html: echoHTML,
                delay: 2
            },
            beforeSend: function () {
                $('#slider0-4').html('Loading...');
            },
            success: function (markup) {
                $('#slider0-4').html(markup);
                $('#slider0-4 img').on('load', function () {
                    //$(this).after('<div>Image loaded</div>');
                    alert('Loaded');
                });
            }
        });
```

([jQuery wait till AJAX page is fully loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10822619/jquery-wait-till-ajax-page-is-fully-loaded)).

This is my first attempt trying to use $.ajax

I cannot get my image to load. I have changed the echoHTML to the image-URL on my server, AND have tried uploading my html on there *thinking it might not work offline*, but to no avail.

My guess is that somethings wrong here "*url: '/echo/html/',*". Have tried using my image in the JSFiddle above there and it loads just fine.

Somebody show me the correct way to do this?

Comment: what is `markuop` outputting?

Comment: /echo/html is part of jsfiddle's ajax api for simulating an ajax request. You will need to have another file which processes your request and sends the markup back. If you do have this, we would need to see the code that is in this file as well.

Comment: http://www.bilalbinsaeed.com/wrc

There is a #slider0-4 in the beginning of the body, and the script is at the bottom, at the preloader's callback function.

Comment: @MarkusKottländer, it stays at 'Loading...' and does not go beyond.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've just been a little mislead by that jsfiddle example.

When the url '/echo/html' is being passed in, it is sending a request to that url, which handles the data that you pass through, and then passes something back to the success function. jsFiddle allows you to simulate ajax requests because they have an Echo API which has these pages built.. but when you call it, it is trying to call `http://www.bilalbinsaeed.com/echo/html/`, which does not exist.. which is throwing an error, which means the success function will not run properly.

You will need to create another file which handles your ajax request. I would recommend doing a little more research into what AJAX is, and how it works.

Comment: You are right. A little more research is what I DO need. 

But just for the matter here, can you tell me if I'm close to what I want to do, or going in a completely wrong direction?

All I wanna do is fetch an image through this method :(

Comment: If you know the filename of the image you want to load, then I do not see why you would even need to use AJAX at all. It looks like you just want to delay the load by 2 seconds? If so, something like this should work, and be much simpler: http://jsfiddle.net/DLy6j/88/

Comment: Actually.

Let me begin here. I have this website that has a preloader. 
I want it to load all the content in the site EXCEPT the main-slider's images (cause they're heavy).
I want them to load once the preloader has been closed and the user has entered the site.

I thought this method could fit. Guess I'm wrong?

Comment: You're not wrong, you could absolutely use AJAX here.. You wouldn't even need to pass in any data.. if you just had an html file with all your images in it, you could just grab that page and load it's contents back. You would just need to create a second page to send your request too. I suggested just using a timeout to load your html as a 'string' in javascript just because it seems simpler to not make a separate file, but it's totally up to how you want to approach this task.

Comment: I don't know much about jsfiddle's echo api, but I believe that when you send a request to /echo/html, that page is essentially an empty page.. the 'html' parameter that you pass through as data basically creates a pseduo-html page, using that line... So, if you essentially take this exact same script, put the echoHTML into a separate file (and no need to pass it in as data anymore), then that would be the proper way to replicate this on your own server. (And of course, use the proper url to that file, rather than /echo/html)

Comment: //$("#wrapper").append($("#container").load("content.html")); 
Initially I tried this, but it didn't work with Chrome since they've some issue with .load method.
However, I'm getting you. I will research on adding content from a second page since the AJAX method seems perfect, and it has a callback once the content has finished loading, just what I need.

Thank you. I will get back to you if I run accross more issues? :/
So, thanks in advance for that :)
Ps. Happy New Year!

Comment: Okay say I change the url: from /echo/html to the URL of 2nd-page that has the <img src="***.jpg" /> tag,
what about the 'data' option for that called the echoHTML variable?

There should be no variable as the string is now in the 2nd-page.

Comment: That's correct, and the delay parameter is also something used by that echo API, so you won't want to use that either. Just leave out the whole 'data' section. Instead, set your delay using that `setTimeout()` function, either around your entire AJAX function, or within the success function.

Comment: Hurray! :)

It works.
Thank you SO much.

Gonna start playing with it now, can't wait :)

Answer (score 0):

It loads an image for me. It is a little unclear what you are asking, but it seems like you  are getting hung up on getting it to load from JSFiddle to your site. Don't try to do that. Cross-Origin Resource Sharing won't work on JSFiddle without changing the headers on your site.

Comment: yeah I thought that too at first. apparently it does exist. http://jsfiddle.net/echo/html/

Comment: Its not my code, and it works fine in JSFiddle. I replace the image's URL to my image's URL and it loads fine. 

I am sorry, I am really, really new to this. Been trying http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ but its above my head atm.

Comment: What is the *url* string anyway?
I tried removing it so it goes back to default and that makes a strang thing happen. (In chrome, the whole of my website loads where I want the IMG tag to load, and in Firefox, nothing loads at all)

Comment: @user3063871 I am not having the issue with it stuck at loading. I think what you should do is hit the checkmark on the answer :-), take a break, enjoy the holiday, and read more on Ajax/jQuery.

Comment: @user3063871 don't check my answer. Check BlakeMann's

Comment: @TJonS :)

I wanna get this thing done. :(
I know I am way beyond my comfort-zone but I have to get this to work..
one way or the other.